# The Lua in 64-bit Redis incorrect cast strings with big numbers

Tags: redis, casting, lua, bignum

I call this lua script in redis:

`return tonumber('1572340499577')`

But Redis returned 382469241

It's fail.

Test in lua console interpreter:

```
> print(tonumber("1572340499577"))
1572340499577 -- As expected
```

64-bit Redis use 32-bit lua? How I work with big numbers as real numbers in redis?

I used Redis 4.0.14 on 64-bit Debian Linux.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with 4.0.14 (using Docker).

Comment: You really use a "clean" v. 4.0.14 redis dist? No any pathes, plugins,clutches etc?
Docker dist is a blackbox.

My configuration is
`vasya@dev-pc:~# redis-server -v`
`Redis server v=4.0.14 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64`
`build=2fd07f570bbe0822`

System
`Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)`
`Release:        8.11`
`Codename:       jessie`

Comment: It ain't a blackbox - the Dockerfile is available, and yes, it is really "clean" :)